# Set bash variable equal to result of string where newlines are replaced by spaces

Tags: bash, sed, newline, tr

I have a variable equal to a string, which is a series of key/value pairs separated by newlines.

I want to then replace these newline characters with spaces, and set a new variable equal to the result

From various answers on the internet I've arrived at the following:

```
#test.txt has the content:
#test=example
#what=s0omething

vars="$(cat ./test.txt)"

formattedVars= $("$vars" | tr '\n' ' ')
echo "$taliskerEnvVars"
```

Problem is when I try to set `formattedVars` it tries to execute the second line:

```
script.sh: line 7: test=example
what=s0omething: command not found
```

I just want `formattedVars` to equal `test=example what=s0omething`

What trick am I missing?

Comment: Remove `cat` and just use `formattedVars=$(tr '\n' ' ' < test.txt)`

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. You are on the wrong track and getting answers that will help you implement that wrong track rather than solve your problem the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line to:

```
formattedVars=$(tr '\n' ' ' <<< "$secretsContent")
```

Notice the space of `=` in your code, which is not permitted in assignment statements.

I see that you are not setting `secretsContent` in your code, you are setting `vars` instead.

Comment: A space after is permitted (but does not behave as you could expect), it's before that is a syntax error. His actual problem is using the variable `$secretsContent` as if it was a command

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use an array to hold contents of the file:

```
readarray -t vars < ./test.txt   # bash 4
```

or

```
# bash 3.x
declare -a vars
while IFS= read -r line; do
  vars+=( "$line" )
done < ./test.txt
```

Then you can do what you need with the array. You can make your space-separated list with

```
formattedVars="${vars[*]}"
```

, but consider whether you need to. If the goal is to use them as a pre-command modifier, use, for instance,

```
"${vars[@]}" my_command arg1 arg2
```